# How to plot the density curve of a vector containing missing values in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set with some NA values (missing values).

Because I need to plot some density curves from this data, I've created the following function:

```
plotDistribution = function (x) {
    N = length(x)
    hist( x,col = "light blue",
          probability = TRUE)
    lines(density(x), col = "red", lwd = 3)
    rug(x)
}
```

It works just fine if x has no missing values but because my data do contain missing values I'm getting the following message: *Error in density.default(x) : 'x' contains missing values*.

My question is: how to plot the density curve of the non-missing values in a data set? How can I ignore the NA and plot the curve as if they don't exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work just adding na.omit()

```
plotDistribution = function (x) {
  N = length(x)
  x <- na.omit(x)
  hist( x,col = "light blue",
        probability = TRUE)
  lines(density(x), col = "red", lwd = 3)
  rug(x)
  print(N-length(x))
}
```

This function can hide data bugs in many cases, so i added a line that print the number of ommited values.

Comment: It works just fine! And that final touch is great. This method is creating a weird barcode below the graph [link](https://puu.sh/BSUK7/602adfa8c8.png), any ideia how to remove it? Just for aesthetics.

Comment: @Mr.Uselessrobot it's caused by the rug(x) function. It's useful because it represents the count of observations in each bar. If you want to delete it, just comment the rug(x) line. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can just take the non missing values of x in the function, such as:

```
plotDistribution = function (x) {
  NoMissing <- x[!is.na(x)]
  N = length(NoMissing)
  hist( NoMissing,col = "light blue",
        probability = TRUE)
  lines(density(NoMissing), col = "red", lwd = 3)
  rug(NoMissing)
}
```